# width: 100% is not working on children div if parent div has width: calc(100% - 300px)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following arrangement:
I have parent `div` with class `container` with `width: 100%;` and also both `html` and `body` have `width: 100%`, and so far it is working as expected.
But inside `div` with class `container`, i have two `div`s, one `div` with `width: 300px`,
and other div with `width: calc(100% - 300px)`,

where parent with class `mainpage` has `width: calc(100% - 300px)`, and child `div` with class `page` has `width: 100%`;
but `width: 100%` is not working on this `div`?

even though parent `div` `width` is determinant.

code: https://jsfiddle.net/tj8k0nnw/1/

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.sidebarcontainer {
  width: 300PX;
  height: 2000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.innersidebarcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 293px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 700px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainpage {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 3000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: teal;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: purple
}

.test1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
}

.test2 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="test1"></div>
        <div class="test2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--
    -->
  <div class="mainpage">
    <div class="page"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code provided is working. You have not specified a height for `page` so the height is 0. Giving it a height causes it to become visible: https://jsfiddle.net/kvjw9vhm/

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.sidebarcontainer{
  width: 300PX;
  height: 2000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.innersidebarcontainer{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar{
  width: 293px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 700px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.mainpage{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 3000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: teal;
}
.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* was width: 100%; */
  background-color: white;
}
.footer{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: purple
}
.test1{
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
}
.test2{
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer">
      <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="test1"></div>
          <div class="test2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainpage">
      <div class="page"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: But div with class 'page' already has width:100%, and height:100%;?

Comment: In your code it is `width: 100%` and `width: 100%` both times.

Comment: Here is a problem! if I add something to the div with the class page, then it is moved down!. what is the problem.? for example add <h1>text</h1> to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Above provided code is working , just add some height in page class.

```
.page{
width: 100%;
height:100px;
background-color: green;
}
```

By **default height is 0 ,if there's no content** .Below is demonstration, check it out:

```css
.mainpage{
width: calc(100% - 300px);
padding: 5px;
padding-right: 2px;
height: 3000px;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: teal;
}
.page{
width: 100%;
height:100px;
background-color: green;
}
.footer{
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer">
        <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
                <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="test1"></div>
                <div class="test2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--
--><div class="mainpage">
    <div class="page"></div>
   </div> 
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Here is a problem! if I add something to the div with the class page, then it is moved down!. what is the problem.? for example add <h1>text</h1> to the page

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is not much problem with your code and you did a typo by mentioning `width` twice in the `.page` class. Changing one of them to `height` worked fine for me and should work for you too.
Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Here is a problem! if I add something to the div with the class page, then it is moved down!. what is the problem.? for example add <h1>text</h1> to the page.